# react-redux Unexpected Action Type Passed to React Action from React Class (Works Fine with React Component)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm new to React and I've been able to get `react-router`, `react-redux`, and `Immutable` to work together.  In one of my component files I have a `handleItemClick()` method in my React component which works as expected:

**mortgage.js**

```
import import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changeActiveMenu } from '../actions/action';

class Mortgage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleItemClick (e, { name }) { //name reflects the routeName
        const activeItemProp = this.props.app.get('primaryMenuActiveItem');
        this.props.changeActiveMenu("test1", "test2");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Route Name=[" +this.props.route.name +"]");
        console.log(this.props.app);
        const activeItemProp = this.props.app.get('primaryMenuActiveItem');
        return (
          <div>
            <h4>{activeItemProp}</h4>
            <button onClick={this.handleItemClick}>Send Action</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(
    state => ({ app: state.get('app'),routing: state.get('routing') }),
    { changeActiveMenu }
)(Mortgage)
```

My action is very simple:

**action.js**

```
export function changeActiveMenu(activeItem) {
  return {
    type: 'CHANGE_MENU',
    payload: {
      activeItem: activeItem
    }
  };
}
```

And here is my app reducer:

**app_reducer.js**

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  primaryMenuActiveItem: "overviewPrimary",
  secondaryMenuActiveItem: 'home'
});

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      console.log("action.type=[" +action.type +"]");
    if (action.type === "CHANGE_MENU") { //use the change primaryMenuActiveItem and secondaryMenuActiveItem
    if(action.payload.activeItem.indexOf('Primary') >= 0) { //dealing with primaryMenu
      return state.merge({ //returning new state
        primaryMenuActiveItem: action.payload.activeItem
      })
    }
    else { //dealing with secondaryMenu
      return state.merge({ //returning new state
        secondaryMenuActiveItem: action.payload.activeItem
      })
    }
  }
  return state; //returns initial state
}
```

I get the expected `action.type` value `"CHANGE_MENU"` from the `console.log()` within my app reducer:

```
action.type=[CHANGE_MENU]
```

MY PROBLEM is when I try to implement the same code within my React class (line 6 in main.js).  I leverage the same action and app reducer files from above.  In my React Class, which is part of my Main component:

**main.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { changeActiveMenu } from '../../actions/action';

const PrimaryMenu = React.createClass({
  handleItemClick (e, { name }) { //name reflects the routeName
     changeActiveMenu("primary", name);
   },
  renderMenu(menu) {

    //use primaryMenuActiveItem and secondaryMenuActiveItem
    const routingProp = this.props.routing.get('locationBeforeTransitions').get('pathname');
    console.log(routingProp);
    const primaryMenuActiveItem = routingProp === "/" ? 'overviewPrimary' : routingProp;
    console.log(primaryMenuActiveItem);

    return (
      <div id="primary-menu">
        <Menu pointing>
          <Link to={menu[0].routeName}><Menu.Item name={menu[0].routeName} active={primaryMenuActiveItem === menu[0].routeName} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>{menu[0].menuName}</Menu.Item></Link>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    )
  },
  render() {
    const menu = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div id="menu">
        {this.renderMenu(menu)}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

class Main extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    const {routing} = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <PrimaryMenu app = {this.props.app } routing = {this.props.routing } data={primaryMenuList}/>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ app: state.get('app'),routing: state.get('routing') }),
  { changeActiveMenu }
)(Main)
```

Now my action.type is as follows:

```
action.type=[@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE]
```

I know this has something to do with a `React class vs. component`.  Any ideas?  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log that you saw `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` is presumably an action dispatched by the react-router.

But I see a problem with your second implementation.

In the first example (which `extends React.component`) you've `@connect`ed  imported action `changeActiveMenu` to `Mortgage`. So inside `handleItemClick` you're **dispatching the action** as `this.props.changeActiveMenu("test1", "test2")`.

In the second example (using `React.createClass`), I see you have two components. Main and PrimaryMenu. You have `@connect`ed `changeActiveMenu` to Main, thus Main receives it as props. Then inside PrimaryMenu's `handleItemClick` you're **invoking** the action creator as `changeActiveMenu("primary", name)`.

You might have noticed the words in bold in the above two paragraphs. There is a difference between invoking an action creator and dispatching an action creator.

**Points to ponder:**

- In Redux action creators are functions which `return` an object with a `type` key. The `type` is the target reducer.
- To trigger the target reducer, action creator should be wrapped with a `dispatch` when it is invoked.

So in your second example you're just invoking it, without a wrapping it with a `dispatch`. When you `mapDispatchToProps` (I see you have used a short-hand for the same which is nice) inside `@connect`, the action creators are essentially wrapped with a `dispatch` and passed as props to the component.

So what you can do is:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({ app: state.get('app'), routing: state.get('routing') }),
  { changeActiveMenu }
)(PrimaryMenu)
```

There is no point in connecting state keys `app` and `routing` to Main component as Main doesn't use those props other than passing it to PrimaryMenu. So lets `@connect` everything on PrimaryMenu.

then PrimaryMenu's `handleItemClick`:

```
  handleItemClick (e, { name }) {
     this.props.changeActiveMenu("primary", name);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @free-soul for your wonderful write-up.  This did help me resolve my issue.  You rock!